# How to keep for loop active until it finishes, then put it back to 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a bot that checks for when people send me a message. I want it so when people send me: "!account" it checks through my json files, if the guy sending the message's ID, matches someones ID in the Json files. If it does, I want it to send him his "credits" and "steamid" so far I've got it kind of working:

```
ok = 1;
if(ok == 1) {
    console.log("[SERVER] "+steamID.getSteamID64()+" is asking for his account information.");
    for(r=0;r<config.tradesettings.amountofaccounts+1;r+=1) {
        if(config.accounts[r].steamID == steamID.getSteamID64()) {
            ok = 0;
            console.log("[SERVER] "+ steamID.getSteamID64() +" is asking for his account info, respondig with it.\n")
            client.chatMessage(steamID.getSteamID64(), "\nDisplaying your account on this bot\nBotID: "+config.accounts[r].botID+"\nSteamID: "+config.accounts[r].steamID+"\nBalance: "+config.accounts[r].balance);

            console.log(r);
            return;
        } else {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Now that is working, except it isn't checking through all json files. The for loop only get's activated once, so it only checks the first or second json.
How would I make the for loop active until it finishes searching, then set r = 0

Here is the the json file is called config.json, and here it is.

```
"accounts":[
    {
    "botID":"0",
    "steamID":"2919",
    "balance": 54
    },
    {
    "botID":"1",
    "steamID":"",
    "balance": 0
    },
    {
    "botID":"2",
    "steamID":"",
    "balance": 0
    },
    {
    "botID":"3",
    "steamID":"76561198026027024",
    "balance": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: if you want a loop, inside a function, to process every element in an array, you don't `return` - that exits the function (which you haven't shown)

Comment: inside the for loop use "continue" to keep looping or "break" to stop the loop. That return there is fuking things up.

Comment: Thanks works!! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure that the loop runs through all the items in the json array, your for loop should compare the value of r with the length of the array ***config.accounts***, or ensure that the value ***config.tradesettings.amountofaccounts*** is set to length of the array.

The following code to replace the for loop should make iteration through all the array items.

```
    for(r = 0; r < config.accounts.length - 1; r++) {
        if(config.accounts[r].steamID == steamID.getSteamID64()) {
            ok = 0;
            console.log("[SERVER] "+ steamID.getSteamID64() +" is asking for his account info, respondig with it.\n")
            client.chatMessage(steamID.getSteamID64(), "\nDisplaying your account on this bot\nBotID: "+config.accounts[r].botID+"\nSteamID: "+config.accounts[r].steamID+"\nBalance: "+config.accounts[r].balance);

            console.log(r);
            break;
        }
    }

    return;
```

This should iterate through all the items in the json array.